# Facebook "active access token must be used"

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb) for my node app.
I can get token with the script and I get the `/me` to work. But when I am trying to get `me/accounts?fields=name,id&limit=1000` I get a error.

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

I test my token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) and I got the following result.

```
App ID  foo : bar
User ID 10153192307109460 : Krister Johansson
User last installed this app via API v2.x
Issued  1440597064 (about a minute ago)
Expires 1445781064 (in about 2 months)
Valid   True
Origin  Web
Scopes  manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions, public_profile
```

And if I test my token in the Graph API Explorer, I get no errors and it will list my accounts.

Comment: It's probably how you are setting it in node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got

```
FB.setAccessToken('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN');
```

where `YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN` is your actual Access Token in your code before you make the call?

If so, check the passing of the parameters is like

```
FB.api('me/accounts', { fields: ['id', 'name'], limits: 1000 }, function (res) { ... });
```

Keep in mind that the module is more than two years old and does very likely not reflect the latest Graph API changes.

Comment: Yes, I have that. But it would not work with the `me/` if I did not have setAccessToken.

Comment: Ok, that was just to make sure. I think you also have to change the passing of the parameters: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb#graph-api I updated my answer